# SqlClient data filtering

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclient

From this database, I want to select two users, 321 and 102 where BOOK_TYPE is 1 or 2 and compare their BOOK_NR, if they coincide then save BOOK_COUNT only from USER_ID 102.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT     BOOK_NR, BOOK_COUNT, USER_ID, BOOK_TYPE " +
                                    "FROM       BOOKS " +
                                    "WHERE     (BOOK_TYPE = '1' OR" + "BOOK_TYPE = '2')" +
                                               "AND MONTH(DATE) = '" + DateTime.Today.Month + "'" +
                                    "GROUP BY   BOOK_NR, BOOK_COUNT, USER_ID, BOOK_TYPE ", BookConn);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
string BookNr = (string)reader[0];
int Count = (int)reader[1];
int User = (int)reader[2];
int Type = (int)reader[3];
 if( " HERE I NEED HELP  " )
 {
   " AND HERE :) "
 }
}
reader.Close();BookConn.Close();
```

[image: DATABASE]

> My only solution is as follows

```
        List<string> User321List = new List<string>();
        List<string> User102List = new List<string>();
        if(User == 321 && Type == 1){ User321List.Add(BookNr.Trim());}
        if(User == 102 && Type == 2){ User102List.Add(BookNr.Trim()+"\t"+Count);}
```

and then...

```
        int count = 0;
        foreach (string x in User321List)
        {
            foreach (string y in User102List)
            {
                List<string> part = y.Split('\t').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();
                var z = string.Compare(part[0], x);
                if (z == 0)
                {
                    count += int.Parse(part[1]);
                }
            }
        }
```

but it takes a lot of time to get result..
if someone figured something out of my nightmare please help and sorry for my bad english...

Comment: Firstly in the where clause add AND USER_ID IN (321, 102), this will filter other users you dont need, then you can look at the second issue comparing the records.

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to put data into a query. This particular instance is safe, but in the general case it leaves you crazy-vulernable to sql injection attacks. In this case, you can just use `MONTH(Current_timestamp)`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not". If your title was something like "C# SqlClient..." then be aware that "SqlClient" is part of .NET, not part of C#. Same with every other .NET class that follows "C#" or "VB.NET" in a title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to focus on answering just the first part:

> I want to select two users, 321 and 102 where BOOK_TYPE is 1 or 2 and compare their BOOK_NR, if they coincide then save BOOK_COUNT only from USER_ID 102.

You want to join the table to itself:

```sql
SELECT     b1.BOOK_NR, b1.BOOK_COUNT, b1.USER_ID, b1.BOOK_TYPE 
FROM       BOOKS b1
INNER JOIN BOOKS b2 ON b2.BOOK_TYPE IN ('1','2') 
               AND b2.User_ID = 321 
               AND b1.BOOK_NR = b2.BOOK_NR
WHERE b1.User_ID = 102 AND b1.BOOK_TYPE IN ('1','2') 
    AND MONTH(b1.DATE) = MONTH(current_timestamp) 
    AND MONTH(b2.DATE) = MONTH(current_timestamp)
```

Since one of your concerns was performance -- that the query was too slow -- I also need to ask whether the `BOOK_TYPE` column is a string or a number. If it's a number column, you should omit the single quotes on the values: for example, just use `IN (1,2)` instead of `IN ('1','2')`. This will help performance by avoiding potential per-row conversions and by potentially better matching to indexes.

Comment: You shouldn't encourage the use of the IN clause. Especially in production code.

Comment: I'm more worried about about the correct data types and getting an accurate JOIN. Get it right and **readable** first, and then continue to performance tune if the actual results are too slow. In this case, I suspect he'll have acceptable performance once he's using a join, even with the `IN()`.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is slow, consider splitting the operation in two. Create a SQL Table function so you don't repeat the SQL, passing the users, type and month in as parameters.

Do *not* do an IN (as suggested in comment). Keep in mind that an OR in the WHERE clause will result in *no indexes being used*.

Join the two instances of the table function and let sql do the matching for you. 
e.g.

```
Select * from dbo.UserList('321',1,12) as u321 
   inner join dbo.UserList('102',2,12) as u102
   on u321.field = u102.field
```

BTW... I covered quite a few advanced topics, but the idea is to let SQL do what it does best: JOINS

As a matter of interest, if your sql table function returns many rows, and you ever use them in a sp, remember to use the *option (recompile)* clause ...